# Set relative time using command line

Tags: linux, command-line, date

Using something similar to the date command, is it possible to set the date and time relative to 'now'?

So instead of something like `date +%T -s "10:13:13"` something like `date -s +1h` or something similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the date, you must log in as root (or su/sudo...)

```
echo "Time 1 hour ago ... $(date -d "$(date +%F\ %T) 1 hour ago")"
echo "Time now .......... $(date  +%F\ %T)"
echo "Time in 1 hour .... $(date -d "$(date +%F\ %T) 1 hour")"

sudo date +%F\ %T -s "$(date -d "$(date +%F\ %T) 1 hour")"
echo "Adjusted time ..... $(date  +%F\ %T)"

sudo date +%F\ %T -s "$(date -d "$(date +%F\ %T) 1 hour ago")"
echo "Re-adjusted time .. $(date  +%F\ %T)"
```

output:

```
Time 1 hour ago ... 2012-04-16 21:31:53
Time now .......... 2012-04-16 22:31:53
Time in 1 hour .... 2012-04-16 23:31:53
[sudo] password for .... 
Adjusted time ..... 2012-04-16 23:31:53
[sudo] password for  .... 
Re-adjusted time .. 2012-04-16 22:31:53
```

Answer (score 1):

Recent `date` can now set the date relatively with natural language!

Here is an example using GNU coreutils 8.23

```
# date
Fri Oct  5 16:24:25 UTC 2018
# date --set "10 minutes ago"
Fri Oct  5 16:14:25 UTC 2018
# date --set "10 minutes"
Fri Oct  5 16:24:25 UTC 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your time zone by doing `# dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`. I'm not sure how you would change the time by an arbitrary value, though.